# Is this expression an lvalue or an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue

Look at this expression:

```
T t;    
T& ref = t;
```

**The `ref` expression is an `lvalue` or an `rvalue`?** I believe it's an `rvalue` because `ref` does not *"designates a function or an object"*:

> "An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on
>   the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function
>   or an object."

[open-std draft n3092]

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object), a reference is not a object.

> "The following entities are not objects: value, reference [...]"

I'm in doubt, because `ref` is in the left side of `=`.

Comment: `ref` itself, as an entity, is not an object. Nevertheless, *expression* `ref` does designate an object. Don't mix the entity itself and the *expression* consisting solely of that entity's name. These are different things, which are treated differently.

Comment: @tadman I'm not using class objects definition. See the cppreference link I let there.

Comment: @AnT Which object the expression `ref` designates? That's what I'm not understanding. Would the object be `t`, once `ref` is an alias for it?

Comment: Dup?  Or related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: It's an lvalue reference to an object of T. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, it's a more nuanced term than that and I think AnT did a better job of explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm in doubt, because ref is in the left side of =.

`ref` is a name and therefore an lvalue.

> I believe it's an rvalue because ref does not "designates a function or an object"

It designates the same object as `t` does.

Answer (score 4):

A reference does designate a function or object! It is literally written like that in the standard! See in [[expr.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1):

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.
>   **The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference**,[...]